# phpseclib version

Tags: php

I'm attempting to add CiviCRM to a site based upon the Open Social Drupal distribution.  I'm hitting a brick wall due to a versioning conflict - not with the two systems directly, but to the support systems each requires.

The Open Social distribution requires phpseclib 2.x, while CiviCRM uses phpseclib 1.x.  Due to this conflict, I can't get composer to install CiviCRM.  How difficult would it be to have CiviCRM support phpseclib 2.x?

If this isn't the place to ask this question, please direct me to the correct site.

Comment: There are a couple issues with drupal 8 still. Some of the links here might be useful: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/wikis/drupal8-composer

Comment: I have the reverse problem (and hello again, Demerit!). CiviCRM running, Open Social failing to install.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution to this?